# RewriteCond to catch URLs not ending with /

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to write a RewriteCond to my htaccess file to catch only URL's that DO NOT end with a / .

This is my file so far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./wedding.php?w=$1
```

So I'm trying to pass the "W" GET var only if the URL does NOT end with /

So this will not be rewritten:

```
domain.com/bla/
```

But this will:

```
domain.com/bla
```

Please assist

Cheers!

**Answer:**
This is what I ended up using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./wedding.php?w=$1
```

**Edit For Howlin:**
This is my full htaccess, I have wordpress and a web app living together on the same dir, so if the URL isnt for the webapp it will go to Wordpress:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./wedding.php?w=$1

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /wedding.php?w=$1 [R]
```

The above should only redirect urls that don't exist and don't have a `/` at the end.

Comment: Thanks please see edited answer I ended up using. Are they the same or is yours more preferable?

Comment: Pretty much the same. The only thing with yours is that if you have a url something like `domain.com/bla/h` then it will be redirected.

Comment: Oh so yours is better! thanks i'll use it! :) What does the [R] do?

Comment: What is in your htaccess (you can add it as an edit to your question) and what url are you trying?

Comment: What is wrong with that? If I enter a url that doesn't exist then it will send to the `wedding.php` page, it doesn't show that in the url because you didn't add `[R]` after that rule. But it does redirect it for me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50790/discussion-between-sir-code-a-lot-and-howlin)